# Have a desktop wallpaper show as one image across three monitors?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-11.10, desktop-customization

I am running Ubuntu 11.10, and I have three monitors plugged in. How can I have one single image across every single monitor plugged into the machine?

Answer (score 2):

This works in windows, so i don't see why it wouldn't work on Ubuntu. You need a picture that matches the dimensions of the entire desktop area. So for example you have two monitors running 1440x900, youll need a 2880x900 picture. Set it as the background and set it to TILE. These settings are the same from Windows to Ubuntu. It will start it in the upper left of the left most monitor and tile it accross all monitors. But since the image IS the size of the entire desktop, it technically doesnt tile, you just see one image. I have this as my setup on my 3 monitor work machine.

As long as the other monitor isnt a whole nother workspace on the ubuntu machine, but just an extension of the main monitors desktop area. I think it will still work.

Unfortunately this doesnt work so well if you have any of the monitors rotated so they are not the same as the rest. Basically the desktop has to be a rectangle that can be filled by one image.

Comment: You do realize that the first sentence doesn't make any sense? It might simply work differently on a different system.

Comment: It makes perfect sense because the background properties are the same. Tile across multiple monitors. Tile in ubuntu behaves the same as it does in Windows. I referenced the only reason why it wouldn't work later in the post. So no, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: That statement (that configuration properties are the same) is missing from the post. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Raymond Chen has a detailed explanation (with pictures) as to how this works and how to do it if the monitors are different sizes. This is case the example is a different picture on each monitor, but the solution is to create one giant image. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/24/5083738.aspx

Comment: Correct, you can also stitch 2 or 3 different smaller pictures together in Photoshop or similar, to get the same effect, but in the end, you are still using ONE single image across all monitors.

Comment: Just simple math.